# Connection between HTML elements and DB documents (rows) in foreach

Tags: meteor

I'm learning Meteor from this book http://meteortips.com/book/ and I don't understand how does the element's identification works.

I have got this loop:

```
{{#each player}}
    <li class="player {{selectedClass}}">{{_id}} {{name}}: {{score}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Inside player variable is this:

```
'player': function(){
    return PlayersList.find();
},
```

PlayersList is some collection with players and their score.

How is it possible that "this._id" of "li" element returns the same value as {{_id}} in "each" loop?

```
   'click li.player': function(){
        var playerId = this._id;
   }
```

If "li" element is inside "each" loop then Meteor sets it automatically values which are in fileds of looped document (PlayersList), which are then accessible via "this" keyword? Or what can be generally accessible via "this" keyword?

Thank you for every explanation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Meteor templating there is a notion of current data context, you can set this current data context using several methods :

- The `{{#each}}` block helper sets the current data context to the currently iterated over item of the collection (`Mongo.Collection` cursor or plain array).
- The `{{#with}}` block helper sets the current data context to whatever argument you pass in.
- Using the template inclusion syntax you can pass the current data context as argument (`{{> myTemplate dataContext}}`), likewise you can dynamically include any template along with any data context using the dynamic template inclusion syntax `{{> Template.dynamic template="myTemplate" data=dataContext}}`
- Using `iron:router` you can assign your routes a template along with a data context (in a way similar to dynamic template inclusion).

The consequence is that inside template helpers and template events in JS, the this keyword always refers to the current data context.

- In the case of helpers, the current data context is the same as where the helper is invoked in the Spacebars template (HTML).
- In the case of events, the current data context is the one that corresponds to the target of the element.

In particular it means that in the `click li.player` event, the current data context will be the one of the `<li>` item, which is the player document iterated over by the `{{#each}}` loop.

There is also other options to access the current data context, there is a read-only `data` [property](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_data) declared on template instances, and a special [function](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata) called `Template.currentData()`.

This is admittedly a bit confusing and one of the upcoming features of the next version of Blaze (the Meteor templates rendering engine) is to address this by ensuring better coherence and better readability.